# libvirt python for windows

Tags: python, libvirt

I am trying to create a python script that runs on Windows to remotely control libvirt managed VMs (on a Linux system). If I try to `pip install libvirt-python` I get the error `Exception: pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python`. I tried getting prebuilt dlls for pkg-config but then it errors out trying to find `libvirt.pc`. Does anyone have any experience with doing something like this?

The libvirt wiki only says that I can [download virt-viewer](https://libvirt.org/windows.html) but nothing about python support for Windows. It seems like the python API is only supported on Linux systems? Are there alternative libraries that I could use? The goal is to provide a custom interface (on top of virsh/virt-* tools) that can be run remotely for managing VMs.